# How to make a QR code scanner in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React native project, I am using expo to build an application which will scan QR code. for that reason I have installed the following package using this command-

> npm install expo-barcode-scanner

I have followed  the below example given in snack expo-

https://snack.expo.io/BJlFFcp2g

When I run this example on my device it works.

But in my React-native project, when I copy the same code given in **App.js** file, after running the application the camera opens but it shows no result while scanning.

Here is the code-

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Linking, Dimensions, LayoutAnimation, Text, View, StatusBar, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    lastScannedUrl: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._requestCameraPermission();
  }

  _requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({
      hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted',
    });
  };

  _handleBarCodeRead = result => {
    if (result.data !== this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
      LayoutAnimation.spring();
      this.setState({ lastScannedUrl: result.data });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        {this.state.hasCameraPermission === null
          ? <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
          : this.state.hasCameraPermission === false
              ? <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                  Camera permission is not granted
                </Text>
              : <BarCodeScanner
                  onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
                  style={{
                    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                  }}
                />}

        {this._maybeRenderUrl()}

        <StatusBar hidden />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handlePressUrl = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Open this URL?',
      this.state.lastScannedUrl,
      [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          onPress: () => Linking.openURL(this.state.lastScannedUrl),
        },
        { text: 'No', onPress: () => {} },
      ],
      { cancellable: false }
    );
  };

  _handlePressCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ lastScannedUrl: null });
  };

  _maybeRenderUrl = () => {
    if (!this.state.lastScannedUrl) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.url} onPress={this._handlePressUrl}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.urlText}>
            {this.state.lastScannedUrl}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.cancelButton}
          onPress={this._handlePressCancel}>
          <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>
            Cancel
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  bottomBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    padding: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  url: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  urlText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  cancelButton: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  cancelButtonText: {
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

So, I am not getting - what should I do to make the QR code scanner working?
It would be very nice if someone suggests me to solve this or give me any example so that I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have had more success using the library at https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner for QR code scanning. Giving this a try may solve your problem? They have a getting started in the README that I recommend following in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of my QR scanner

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, View, Text, Vibration, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class ExpoScanner extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.onBarCodeRead = this.onBarCodeRead.bind(this);
    this.renderMessage = this.renderMessage.bind(this);
    this.scannedCode = null;

    this.state = {
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
      id_cedulacli: '',
            placa:'',
            monto:'', 
            fecha_pago:'Seleccione fecha'   
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    await this.setState({hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted'});
    await this.resetScanner();
  }

  multaEdit = ({data, type}) =>{

    if ((type === this.state.scannedItem.type && data === this.state.scannedItem.data) || data === null) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ scannedItem: { data, type } });

    const {placa} = this.state;
    const {monto} = this.state;
    const {fecha_pago} = this.state;

    Vibration.vibrate();

    console.log(`EAN scanned: ${data}`);


  fetch('http://10.10.20.88/parciall/editarMul.php', {
    method: 'post',
    header:{
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },          
    body:JSON.stringify({
      placa: placa,
      monto: monto,
      id_cedulacli: ''+`${data}`,
      fecha_pago: fecha_pago,
    })

  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) =>{
      if(responseJson == "Actualización completada"){
        alert(responseJson);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("InicioScreen");
      }else{

        alert(responseJson);

      }             

          })

    .catch((error)=>{
      console.error(error);
    });

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Inicio', { ean: data });

  }

  renderAlert(title, message) {
    Alert.alert(
      title,
      message,
      [
        { text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.resetScanner() },
      ],
      { cancelable: true }
    );
  }

  onBarCodeRead({ type, data } ) {
    if ((type === this.state.scannedItem.type && data === this.state.scannedItem.data) || data === null) {
      return;
    }

    Vibration.vibrate();
    this.setState({ scannedItem: { data, type } });

      console.log(`EAN scanned: ${data}`);
  }

  renderMessage() {
    if (this.state.scannedItem && this.state.scannedItem.type) {
      const { type, data } = this.state.scannedItem;
      return (
        <Text style={styles.scanScreenMessage}>
          {`Scanned \n ${type} \n ${data}`}
        </Text>
      );
    }
    return <Text style={styles.scanScreenMessage}>Focus the barcode to scan.</Text>;
  }

  resetScanner() {
    this.scannedCode = null;
    this.setState({
      scannedItem: {
        type: null,
        data: null
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <BarCodeScanner
            onBarCodeScanned={this.multaEdit}
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          />
          {this.renderMessage()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```